# Assumptions of Nyquist sampling theorem

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis, frequency-spectrum, noise, sampling

Hoping I can save the question and it doesn't get migrated to philosophy stackexchange as Hilmar [said](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64988044#64988044) in any case I don't think it is a different question the question was always meant to be interdisciplinary. Maybe indeed it is closer and a better fit for Philosophy

**How prepared are we to accept the assumptions of Nyquist Theorem (stated to be only 1 i.e. limited bandwidth ≡ no frequencies higher than B hertz)?**

In case it does get migrated to Philosophy Stackexchange

I am thinking the tags should be

1 Epistemology

2 Philosophy of Science

3 Metaphysics

4 Philosophy of Mathematics

5 Philosophy of Physics

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150863/discussion-on-question-by-george-ntoulos-explicit-list-of-assumptions-of-nyquist); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Closing because it's hard to see that it is possible for anyone to provide an answer that OP will accept.

Comment: @PeterK. Now it became an issue of me accepting an answer? I found the last paragraph about practical problems confusing. I could accept the answer had there not been the last paragraph. It was poor wording on my part questioning the acceptability of the assumptions. The mention of wikipedia also confused me but it was a lesser problem. I needed nothing more than the second paragraph. The only requirement......original signal. I am going to improve my wording.

Comment: The [theorem as stated in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem#Introduction) contains all the requirements. A bulleted list is not needed.

Comment: @PeterK. The theorem is the result (it is the statement). It contains in itself one assumption. "no frequencies higher than B hertz". The requirements haven't been made clear by the wikipedia article (I didn't know that was the only one). It was made clear by Hilmar. If anything I don't understand that "no frequencies higher than B hertz" and "the signal is bandlimitted" are equivalent (the same thing). A bulleted list is indeed needed since that was what was asked that was my question (especially now without the acceptability issues). I don't think that is off topic in any way.

Comment: The requirement is: "no frequencies higher than B hertz". You do not appear to be able to accept that as an answer. Unfortunately, the way you're asking the question, there is no other answer mathematically.  The extra things Hilmar mentions are some things that might come up when implementing the mathematics in a physical system. If that's your question, then I'd suggest reading more and asking a follow-up question to this one.

Comment: @PeterK. The things that might come up confuse me. They shouldn't have been mentioned. It is not a matter of me being able to accept the answer or not I just didn't understand that was the only assumption.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you have been reading [but Wikipedia is actually not bad.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)

> What are the (least/minimum sufficient) assumptions for Nyquist sampling theorem to hold?

The only requirement is that the signal is bandlimited, i.e.

$$X(f) = 0, |f| > f_s/2 \tag{1}$$

where $f_s$ is the sample rate and $X(f)$ the Fourier Transform of the original signal $x(t)$.

There are a number of "practical" problems (finite vs infinite length, periodicity in the other domain, residual aliasing, etc) but none of them is fundamental and none of this is in the least bit "metaphysical".

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150862/discussion-on-answer-by-hilmar-explicit-list-of-assumptions-of-nyquist-sampling); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.